# sylius/currency-bundle(errors when getting home page)

Tags: sylius

I installed all sylius/bundles in my app in preinstalled symfony and i also installed summary.html.twig when i try to go my homepage i get this error:
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
 The service "sylius.currency_importer.open_exchange_rates" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "sylius.currency_importer.open_exchange_rates". Did you mean this: "sylius.currency_importer.open_exchange_rates.class"?.
Please can evryone help me thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your `parameters.yml` add `sylius.currency_importer.open_exchange_rates` parameter. Like in https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/app/config/parameters.yml.dist#L21.